# To add records from a csv file to a related list

Tags: salesforce, apex

In the case object, I have a related list "CIM". When users upload an attachment, can I take the records in the attachment and make them part of the CIM related list?(Basically, want to add records in the attachment as records of the CIM object, which has master-detail relationship with Case.)
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank You,
Bijili

Comment: By the way you can ask Salesforce questions directly on [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can, but not easily.  You can add a trigger on before insert of Attachment which looks for attachments on the Case object that are of type CSV.  Then you can parse them with an [Apex CSV parser](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Code_Samples#Parse_an_IETF_RFC_4180-compliant_CSV_File_with_Apex) and add its rows to the CIM object.  Then they'll show up in the related list.

This is easily enough described, but it will take a bit of work to actually do.

Comment: Or maybe this CSV parser would be better for you: http://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/salesforce-apex-csv-parsing-to-sobject/